# Graph Of utilization

Tags: anylogic

My problem is as follows: I would like to create a graph of the percentage use of boxes over 24 hours. However, the box.utilization() function is cumulative, so I tried to solve the problem by creating a dataset that collects the values every hour and an event that resets the utilization so that the next hour is not affected by the previous hour's utilization.
(I attach a picture of the graph I created).
Is there a more efficient way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue before. Here is how I handled it:
Instead of cumulative utilization, I calculate the maximum hourly utilization. That is, I record the number of seized resource for every minute and get an array of 60 elements. Then divide the maximum number in that array by the total number of resources available. An example:

- I have 100 machines
- During an hour, maximum of 60 of them were busy
- 60/100= 60% maximum utilization during that hour
- Then I plot these for each hour.